# Ionic - Where do I keep all the data?

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework, ionic2

Im new in ionic-2 and Im working on a mobile app with login and signup, I want to know how and where I need keep all users' data (user, password and email). Do I need to pay for a server in order to save that info only? Thanks.

Comment: You can save the data on your own server or via or use for example the ionic database: https://docs.ionic.io/services/database/

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options.

1. Keep data on your own database (SQLite,Mongo,etc) - Traditional approach
2. Store it inside the Local storage (this is not reliable)
3. Use 3rd party service like Firebase - Modern and specifically designed for mobile

And of course you can use [**Ionic Services**](https://docs.ionic.io/services/)

If you need to know more about those please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ionic then it makes sense to use their Ionic Auth service.

https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/

They will handle the authentication, registration, etc and there is not too much for you to do. It's also pretty trivial to add in Facebook, Twitter and other forms of social login.

The options that Sampath mentions are all, of course, all decent approaches too.